# How do you use a cell value to find the matching sheet name?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find a way to copy information from one sheet to another. I know how to find the information from the sheet to copy from, but I'm having trouble finding the sheet to copy to. I want to copy to a sheet based off of a value in my original sheet.

I have a list of names in column C, ex. John, Mark, and Will that starts in row 40. I would like to then copy John's row of information to the sheet titled "John", and Mark's information to a sheet titled "Mark", etc. so that each person's information is summarized on their own sheet. I am having trouble using the value found in column C (the person's name), and then using that value to find a sheet with the coordinating name.

```
function CopyInfo() {
var CopyFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
var ColumntoSearch = 3;
var LastRow = CopyFrom.getLastRow();

 //Gets column to search for names to compare
  var Range = CopyFrom.getRange(40, ColumntoSearch, LastRow, 1);
  var Values = Range.getValues();

 //Sets the amount of data to copy over
  var NumberofColumns = 11;
  var NumberofRows = 1;

//Compares all the names in the Summary sheet
 var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<Values.length;i++) {
     var Name = CopyFrom.getRange(i-d+40, 3);
     var CopyTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Name);
    if(Name == ????????){
      var RangetoCopy=CopyFrom.getRange(i-d+40,1,NumberofRows,NumberofColumns); 
     var DestRange=CopyTo.getRange(CopyTo.getLastRow()+1,1,NumberofRows,NumberofColumns);
      RangetoCopy.copyTo(DestRange);
      d++;

     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to copy the values from `Summary` sheet to each sheet with the sheet name retrieved from the column "C" in `Summary` sheet.
- There are values for copying in the column "A:K".
- For example, when the row 45 of `Summary` sheet has the values of `a45, b45, c45, d45, e45, f45, g45, h45, i45, j45, k45`, the values are copied to just below the last row of the sheet name of `c45`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think your script is almost correct. So I modified your script a little.

#### Modified script:

```
function CopyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Added
  var CopyFrom = ss.getSheetByName("Summary"); // Modified
  var ColumntoSearch = 3;
  var LastRow = CopyFrom.getLastRow();

  //Gets column to search for names to compare
  var Range = CopyFrom.getRange(40, ColumntoSearch, LastRow, 1);
  var Values = Range.getValues();

  //Sets the amount of data to copy over
  var NumberofColumns = 11;
  var NumberofRows = 1;

  //Compares all the names in the Summary sheet
  // var d=0; // Removed
  for (var i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
    var Name = Values[i][0]; // Modified
    var CopyTo = ss.getSheetByName(Name); // Modified
    if (Name) { // Modified
      if (!CopyTo) CopyTo = ss.insertSheet(Name); // Added
      var RangetoCopy = CopyFrom.getRange(i + 40, 1, NumberofRows, NumberofColumns); // Modified
      var DestRange = CopyTo.getRange(CopyTo.getLastRow() + 1, 1, NumberofRows, NumberofColumns);
      RangetoCopy.copyTo(DestRange);
      // d++; // Removed
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, if the sheet name is not found, new sheet of the sheet name is inserted. If you don't want to insert new sheet, please replace `if(!CopyTo) CopyTo = ss.insertSheet(Name)` to the following script.

  ```
  if (CopyTo) {
    var RangetoCopy = CopyFrom.getRange(i + 40, 1, NumberofRows, NumberofColumns); 
    var DestRange = CopyTo.getRange(CopyTo.getLastRow() + 1, 1, NumberofRows, NumberofColumns);
    RangetoCopy.copyTo(DestRange);
  }
  ```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Elise I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.